# How do I write a script to find the cost of each item in a list if only the total cost is known? MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to write a script in MATLAB for my class. The scenario is that there are four different types of pens. I only know the total cost of all four pens (total is not actually given to me). I am trying to find the individual cost of each different type of pen. My 3 "friends" also each bought the four pens themselves. That makes for a total of 16 pens among 4 people. Everyone's total cost should be the same. The book suggests creating a matrix for the pens made up of columns for each different type of pen and rows for each of the people (4x4). It also says to have a column vector for the totals each person spent on the pens, which I presume would all be the same. I am stuck and really not sure how to go about solving this since I do not know the cost of even one of the pens. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Unfortunately, the question you're really asking is not about Matlab, but about how to do linear algebra.  If all four people paid the same prices for the pens and they all bought the same pens, the prices of the individual pens cannot be found.  So, it sounds like this is a trick question, or you're missing something about what's actually being asked.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. I think I interpreted it incorrectly. I believe that the correct interpretation is: there are four different types of pens. The four people all bought the same types of pens, but could have bought varying quantities of the different types and total quantity of pens, and as a result, have different total costs.

Comment: I have not taken linear algebra yet, but I believe this may be what I need to solve it?: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4VAXv6yRULU

Comment: Yes, the revised problem is workable.  You're solving a linear system of equations.  So, you don't need to know linear algebra as its own concept...really, what you're doing is the same as when you solve the equations of two lines to find their intersect.  Take a closer look at your material and try to solve this.  If you cannot, update the question with a correct description and demonstrate some effort in attempting to solve it, then we can help.

Comment: Also, you can use the @ symbol to mention someone in a comment, for instance type `@TTT` to mention me and then I'll get a notification.

Answer (score 1):

@TTT is right, linear algebra solves your task. The great thing about Matlab is, that it can actually calculate linear algebra without the fuzz of building for-loops.
Here is a simple example that should suit your case.

Footnote:
Note that the matrix inversion with `inv()` will be flagged as inefficient by the Matlab-IDE (i.e. the program) because it is much faster and more accurate to calculate `inv(NumPens) * total` jointly (which is expressed as `NumPens\total`) than explicitly calculating the inverse of the matrix first -- but to teach linear algebra, this way is much better!)

```
total = [17;13;12;27]; % vector 4x1 (number of persons x 1)

NumPens = [1 1 3 1
           1 0 1 1
           0 1 0 2
           3 0 1 1]; % matrix 4x4 (number of persons x number of pen types)

% total = NumPens * x % original system
x = inv(NumPens) * total % how to calculate the number of pens
```

Comment: thank yall for your comments! I was able to get it working using MATLABs built in code